# WordPress Ajax request, not loading the correct category**

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm making an ajax request using the following, and instead of returning only content that pertains to specific category, it is returning all of the posts available**  (running this load more on the archive/category page). I should be loading categories with an id of '3' on this particular category page.

Any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated

```
$('#load-more').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pageCount = $(this).attr('data-page');
    var nextPage = parseInt($(this).attr('data-page')) + 1;
    var catID = $(this).attr('data-cat');
    console.log(catID);
    if ($(this).hasClass('shake')) {
        (this).removeClass('shake');
    }
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action': 'more_posts',
            'pageCount': pageCount,
            'cat': catID,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.message);
            if (data.message === "nomore") {
                console.log('none');
            } else {
                $('#appended-content').append(data.message);
            }
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            $('#load-more').attr('data-page', nextPage);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.message);
        }
    });
});
```

If I manually set it to 3 it works, so If I had to assume, I'm not correcting getting and/or setting the id correctly inside the 'args'

```
add_action('wp_ajax_more_posts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\ajax_more_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_posts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\ajax_more_posts');
function ajax_more_posts()
{
    $cat_id = $_POST['cat'];  //not sure if this is actually getting the category
    $paged = $_REQUEST['pageCount'];
    $cat = $_REQUEST['dataCat'];
    ob_start();
    $args = [
        'cat' => $cat_id, //if I set to 3 manually it works
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ];
    if ($paged != "") {
        $args['paged'] = $paged;
    }
    // if($cat != ""){
    //     $args['cat'] = $cat;
    // }
    $moreBlogPosts = new WP_Query($args);
    $html = '';
    if ($moreBlogPosts->have_posts()) {
        while ($moreBlogPosts->have_posts()) : $moreBlogPosts->the_post();
            $id = get_the_ID();
            $cats = get_the_category($id);
            echo '<div class="post-preview">';
            include(locate_template('partials/posts/preview-components/preview-block.php', false, false));
            get_template_part('partials/posts/preview-components/shopstyle-carousel');
            echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo "nomore";
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $message = ob_get_clean();
    echo json_encode(['message' => $message]);
    die();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me a link of the example?

Comment: @AhmedGinani sorry, it's all local

Comment: check and alert if you are getting catID correct : alert(catID);

Comment: @AhmedGinani the catID is correct, alerts and consoles correctly

Comment: try to change $_POST[ 'cat' ] to $_REQUEST[ 'cat' ] , also try to pass it like cat': parseInt(catID),

Comment: @AhmedGinani, sorry that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be good if you can use $.post instead of $.ajax in this case.

```
var data={
          'action': 'more_posts',
          'pageCount': pageCount,
          'cat': catID,
}
$.post(ajaxurl, data,function(res){
    var json_obj = JSON.parse(res);     
    $('#appended-content').append(json_obj.message);
    //your code here        
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this worked great.  What about this caused it to work though exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the method in the Ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: targetUrl,
    success: function(data){

    },
    complete: function (data) {

    }
});
```

So, by default, the requests are sending out as GET method. That's the reason behind this.

There is two way to fix this.

*Method 1: Add a method in your Ajax call*

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: targetUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(data){

    },
    complete: function (data) {

    }
});
```

*Method 2: Change your server-side script to accept GET request (you can use $_GET or $_REQUEST)*

Example: $_REQUEST[ 'cat' ]  or $_GET[ 'cat' ]